# Copy column from one Excel sheet to another Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy particular columns from one Excel sheet to another Excel sheet in a different workbook. How can I use a macro to copy some columns to different Excel sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have two workbooks (source and target) and you want to copy column A in the source workbook to column A in the target workbook.

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")

    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

Clearly you can change the columns as you see fit.