# Copy columns from one Excel sheet to another, skipping columns in between

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy column from one Excel sheet to another Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382526/copy-column-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-excel-sheet)

I have 5 sheets in my Excel file. Out of these 5, one is the master sheet which has all the data I want to copy to the other 4 sheets.
All the sheets have one common column, ID. The master has more than 10000 IDs.

What I want to do is:

If ID in sheet1 = 24356 = ID in master sheet then copy x, y, z columns from master sheet to sheet1. This is same for all other sheets.

Also, since the master sheet is from another source than the rest of the sheets, its formatting is different. Is there a way to remove all formatting in sheets before running copy/paste?

Can anyone please tell me the VBA code to do this.

This is what my Master sheet looks like:

[image]

I want the other sheet (e.g. sheet1) in this case to look like:

[image]

Also, while searching the master sheet, is it possible for the code to look through the last column of the sheet?

Comment: I think you can use 'VLOOKUP' with the ID to get the result you need. No need for VBA.

Comment: @Remnant: I tried to use this but its giving me a "Type mismatch error"

Sub Data()
Dim result As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FMed")
Set sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Workingtest")
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet.Range("C:C"), sheet1.Range("A:D"), 1, False)
End Sub

Comment: @Remnant: There are more than 10,000 IDs. It would very time consming entering vlookup in every cell. Also, I tried vlookup and what it is doing is that it is copying colA to colA, ColB to ColB etcc. As in the question above, the two excel sheets have same column headings but they are in different columns. I dont know how to fix that in vlookup or VBA?

Comment: see my answer below. You don't need to enter 10,000x - once set up for one row it is cut and paste:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nupur

Here is the non-VBA way.

Assume your master data is on a sheet called `Master` and the data is in range `A1:H9`. Now assume I have `Sheet1` with a list of IDs in range `A2:A5`.

```
 1   ID    Name    Type    Question1    Type3    Type4
 2   475
 3   479
 4   501
 5   503
```

Then in `Sheet1` in cell `B2` I have the following to retrieve `Name` for `ID=475`:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Master!$A$2:$H$9,2,0) //returns f1
```

To get `Type` for `ID=475` I use:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Master!$A$2:$H$9,3,0) //returns adm1
```

All I am doing is setting up a reference to the data table on `Master` (note absolute ref with $ signs), using ID as the lookup value, and then changing the column value (3rd input in VLOOKUP) to retreive the relevant value.

Once you have set this up for the first row you can then just copy down and get the right data populated.

Does this solve the issue?

Comment: +1 For the NON VBA approach :)