# Copy certain cells to a new workbook/sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I've had a thorough search through previous questions, but I can't find quite what I'm looking for.

Daily I have to download a file from the internet, the columns of which are always the same, but the values (in all but the title row) are the different. There are many columns which I don't need to pay attention to.

I'd like to be able to create a macro that I will link to a button in Excel that will:
Take certain columns from one sheet, and paste them to a new blank sheet or workbook.

Most of the results I've found when searching seem to contain rules: "if something", or "when ...", etc. - I don't need this.

I'm just trying to make something that will take: Column: C, N, AC, AG, AZ, etc. and paste them to column A, B, C, D, etc. in another blank sheet.

Comment: Sure We can help if you show us some efforts your self :) To start with do you know how to record a macro?

Comment: Hi, thanks for having a look. I understand how vba code works, and did a little in high school. But the technicalities of coding.. that I can't do...yet. I know how to record a macro, I'm aware of defining things like variables at the start (when writing one). I could also probably edit one to fix/change things if I found the code. Let me know if there's anything else I can provide/try/do. Thanks

Comment: Like Siddharth said, I would press the record button, copy and paste all of the columns that I need, and then start with the recorded code.

Comment: Perfect :) Record a macro to `Column: C, N, AC, AG, AZ, etc.. and paste them to column A,B,C,D etc... in another blank sheet.` What do you get?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'll try that. I don't have access to the file I need just now - will have it tomorrow. I didn't think it would be as simple as recording what I needed the macro to do! I'll try that tomorrow & post the results. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy column from one Excel sheet to another Excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382526/copy-column-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, writing the code to do that is pretty simple.  Just create a button and a click method, and then put something like this into the body of the method:

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

You'll need to do the meat of this for each column, but if you create a nice UI for the user, it could all be done in code.

Comment: For a variety of reasons, it's much better to do this in one line: `Sheets("Sheet3").Columns("A:A").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1")`

Comment: + 1 @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I agree.