# Excel Macro to copy certain columns from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first attempt to write VBA code. I am mimicking something I found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382526/copy-column-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-excel-sheet).

I want to copy certain columns (A, B and E) from one workbook to another and also change the font and color of certain Rows and edit the text in certain cells (replace a long phrase with the word "Group").

This is the code I copied without change:

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

I get a runtime error 9 and the line below is highlighted:

```
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")
```

I am attaching the Source and Target files below as I hope they would look like at the end of a successful run.

[Source File](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4tcwo2ZvQCRWkxxOU5xOGNSY2s)

[Target File](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4tcwo2ZvQCRV0l2SmxHZkh6NFU)

Comment: Either you do not have a workbook names Source or the workbook does not have a sheet named sheet1. The code works so it is a reference to one of the objects which is either the sheet or workbook.  I reviewed the source doc and you do not have a sheet named sheet1.  I will post the fix in the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You reference a sheet that is not there.  Change it to reference the first sheet in the workbook by using its index.  You also did not include the extension to the file so it would fail on the workbook object as well.

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That totally works. Now I am gonna try and figure out how to copy rows conditional on the heading appearing, changing font and color and text. I will present my code when I get somewhere or get stuck somewhere so I can get comments. Thank you!!

Comment: thanks yes ofcourse. Also, if you can, can you tell me how to copy the first cell of a given row if it contains some text, till the source excel runs out of rows. Thanks.

Comment: @Amatya I would be more than happy to but can you put it in another questions so we do not get the two topics intermixed.

Comment: @Sorceri Sorry this is an old post. I have a query. If I need to copy few columns (Not in sequence) like B, D, E to destination file G,H,I, how can I achieve that

Comment: @SandeepThomas  you could create an array of the columns then use a for loop to go through them all.  It may be better to post a question with your code.